# Power BI: Select one outcome record per patient, if follow up time range is dynamic (user selected) and some patients have multiple records in range?

Tags: powerbi, filtering, calculated-columns, measure

This is a problem I’ve been wrestling with for awhile. I am relatively new to Power BI so I may be missing something obvious. I have Googled thoroughly searching for help, but no other examples quite fit my situation. Thank you for your patience!

My data are clinical forms called “CTOPs” which collect standardised data items on patients. Patients have an assessment CTOP when they first attend a clinic, then follow up CTOPs done at intervals if they keep attending. In the dataset, a patient may have only one Assessment CTOP, or an Assessment plus one, or two, or even several, follow up CTOPs.

My report displays a summary of change on each data item between the Assessment and Follow up CTOPs for groups of patients, using mainly column and doughnut visuals. There are slicers to enable the end user to select patient groups by presenting problem, types of treatment, sex, age range and clinic location.
I have implemented calculations and measures for all the outcomes I need. This is not where my problem lies.

Among the other slicers, the output report allows the end user to select:

1. The date range of Assessment CTOPs (new patients) they want to see outcomes for. For example, they may want to see outcomes for all new patients who attended in 2022 – so, between 1/1/22 and 31/12/22.
2. The follow up range (weeks) they are interested in. For example, the user may want to see outcomes between 8 and 16 weeks after the patients first attended. Or they may want to look at longer term outcome – say 36-60 weeks (roughly 9-12 months).

The problem is that some patients have multiple follow up CTOPs completed in the follow up range selected by the user. I need to be able to filter my report visuals so they only contain one outcome record per patient. I would default this to the most recent CTOP date available.

**Using an example to illustrate:**

The end user has selected to look at outcomes from new patients who attended in 2022. The follow up period they choose is 8-16 weeks. I use UK date format: dd/mm/yyyy.
A new patient attends on 16/10/22 and has an Assessment CTOP done. They attend for follow-up on 22/11/22 (5 weeks after Assessment), 3/1/23 (11 weeks after Assessment) and 1/2/23 (15 weeks after). Both the 1st and the 2nd follow up CTOP fall into the desired follow up range of 8-16 weeks. So at the moment, my report includes this patient twice. I want to be able to exclude the earlier (1st) follow up done on 22/11/22.

| Encounter ID | Assessment CTOP date | Follow up CTOP date | Weeks To Follow up | Latest follow up date in selected follow up range? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | 16/10/22 | 22/11/22 | 5 | No |
| 1001 | 16/10/22 | 3/1/23 | 11 | No |
| 1001 | 16/10/22 | 1/2/23 | 15 | Yes |

Because the outcome time frame is user-selectable, I can’t “hardcode” filters into my tables, as the relevant follow up CTOP per patient I want included is going to change depending on user inputs.
How can I dynamically use a filter (parameter, measure etc) to take the user-selected slider values for follow up time period – 2 integers, being min and max weeks – and filter for the latest available record per client ID within that period?

**Things I have tried/considered:**

- Delete multiple follow up CTOPs from the dataset as part of the data cleaning steps: I don’t want to do this, as deleted data may be relevant to other outcome/patient groups selected by the end users.
- Hard-code: read value of min and max follow up ranges, have a calculated column to flag the latest follow up CTOPs done per patient within that follow up range. Refresh dataset after user chooses min and max, to recalculate the flag. Doesn’t work – I didn’t think it would – as columns are not dynamic.
- A measure that the visuals are filtered by: but the types of visuals I have (predominantly doughnuts and column charts) do not allow filtering by measures. Other types of visuals do, but they aren’t suitable for my outputs.

I did manage to **code and test a measure** however. The code is:

```
HighestWTFinDateRange =
VAR endWTF='Follow up max'[Follow up max value]
VAR startWTF='Follow up min'[Follow up min Value]
return
IF(
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('FU CTOPs'[WeekstoFUfrac]),
        FILTER(ALLEXCEPT('FU CTOPs','FU CTOPs'[ENCOUNTER_ID]),
            AND('FU CTOPs'[Weeks_to_followup]>=startWTF, 'FU CTOPs'[Weeks_to_followup] <=endWTF)))
        =MAX('FU CTOPs'[WeekstoFUfrac])
    ,1,0)
```

- HighestWTFinDateRange is a flag (0/1) to indicate which rows have the longest Weeks to Follow up (WTF) value for each patient. Patients have unique identifier [ENCOUNTER_ID].
- ‘Follow up max’ and ‘Follow up min’ are tables with the full range (integer) of weeks to follow up possible in the dataset. ‘Follow up max’[Follow up max value] is a measure taking the user-selected maximum follow up value (weeks, integer) they want (read from a slider on the report), and in the same way ‘Follow up min’[Follow up min Value] is the minimum follow up value selected.
- The main data table is ‘FU CTOPS’. [WeekstoFUfrac] is a calculated column, the number of fractional weeks, per line of data, between completion of the same patient’s Assessment CTOP and the follow up CTOP. (Some patients have more than one CTOP completed in the same week although it is not standard process. So I needed to use the continuous/fractional measure here. But I don’t want users to be able to select fractional weeks.)

**Back-up solution:**

A back up I am implementing: have standardised/set follow up ranges for the user to select. Hard code for a range of possibilities. This will restrict flexibility, but it would get rid of the multiple CTOP outcomes per patient problem.

Thank you for reading if you have made it this far! I am happy to give further information if needed. Any help will be appreciated, or confirmation if what I want isn’t possible.